# Add a Mapinfo TabFile in Geotools goes wrong [Automatically Converts my Integer values to Byte]

Tags: ogr, java, geotools

we have read Mapinfo Tab file in Geotools using `JniOGRDataStoreFactory`, but when we execute filter statement on feature collection it give some vague values so we decide to investigate it and found that it create some attributes with byte data type that originally are integer.

**Console Image from Eclipse After Reading using JniOGRDataStoreFactory**
[image]

**Mapinfo tools screen shot.**

[image]

now my problem is that how can we read that attribute values correctly, Please advice.

Comment: do you get the same effect when using ogr2ogr on the commandline?

Comment: when i convert my Mapinfo file to CSV file using **ogr2ogr**  it gives correct values. and one more thing we have used ogr2ogr in `C#` using its DLLs it gives me the correct value as well.
The problem is only in geotools . As Mapinfo also gives correct values.

Comment: @iant you can take [File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6xgnv85gwlsu8qs/HSDPA.rar?dl=0) as input file for check.

Comment: can you create a minimal working example to show the bug complete with input data and create a bug report https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOT/

Comment: @iant as you suggested we have reported above bug. The bug link is given below. [BugLink](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5588)